# FindFit low speed when fitting polynomial coefficients: is it possible to significantly increase the speed?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, polynomials, approximation, modeling, frequency

I work in Mathematica with a Butterworth filter, the transfer function of which depends on the selected order and cutoff frequency.

I want to evaluate the change in the location of the roots on the complex plane if I slightly modify the frequency response of the filter. To do this, I create a data set of the amplitude-frequency characteristics, select a model with custom parameters (the roots are custom parameters) and fit it to the data using *FindFit*.

**There are no problems with this, but the problem in another thing.**

If I choose the high order of the model ($n=8$ and above), then the speed of the *FindFit* will decrease sharply. For example, for the order $n = 8$ it took me about 15 - 20 minutes.

I tried to change the calculation method, but it didn’t really affect anything.

I try different methods, and the usual *FindFit*, and *Nminimize*.

Are there any tricks to increase the calculation speed and make it more or less convenient?

Here is my code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

pars = {n = 3} (*Order of model*)

btf = N[First@ButterworthFilterModel[{"Lowpass", 3, 1}, s]]

tf = btf[[1, 1, 1]]/btf[[2, 1, 1]];

s = ω I;

r = ComplexExpand[Re[tf]] // Simplify;

y = ComplexExpand[Im[tf]] // Simplify;

afc[ω_] = 
 Sqrt[r^2 + y^2] // Simplify;(*Amplitude-Frequency Characteristic*)

data = {#, afc[#]} & /@ Table[ω, {ω, 0, 2, .05}];

lp = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.01]}, 
   DisplayFunction -> Identity];

Show[lp, DisplayFunction -> $DisplayFunction, 
 PlotRange -> Full]

pol = 1/Product[(s - (Subscript[a, k] + Subscript[b, k] I)), {k, 1, n}]

R = ComplexExpand[Re[pol]] // Simplify;

Y = ComplexExpand[Im[pol]] // Simplify;

parameters = Join[Table[Subscript[a, k], {k, 1, n}], Table[Subscript[b, k], {k, 1, n}]]

constraints = Table[Sign[Subscript[a, k]] <= 0, {k, 1, n}]

model = Sqrt[R^2 + Y^2] // Simplify

f1 = FindFit[data, model, parameters, ω]

f2 = FindFit[data, {model, constraints}, parameters, ω, Method -> NMinimize]

p1 = Show[lp, DisplayFunction -> $DisplayFunction, PlotRange -> Full];

p2 = LogLinearPlot[Evaluate[model /. {f1, f2}], {ω, 0, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed}, PlotRange -> Full];

GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}]
```

**EDIT:**

I replaced the lines in the code:

```
R = ComplexExpand [Re [pol]] // Simplify; 

Y = ComplexExpand [Im [pol]] // Simplify; 

model = Sqrt [R ^ 2 + Y ^ 2] // Simplify
```

On the:

```
model = Abs [pol] // Simplify;
```

It began to work faster.

Comment: The part that hangs is not the `FindFit`, but the `ComplexExpand` and `Simplify` for both `R` and `Y`. You can replace these with `Re[pol]`, `Im[pol]`, don't do the expansion or simplify and it completes and I get a plot.

Comment: I replaced the lines in the code

`R = ComplexExpand [Re [pol]] // Simplify;`

`Y = ComplexExpand [Im [pol]] // Simplify;`

`model = Sqrt [R ^ 2 + Y ^ 2] // Simplify`

On the:

`model = Abs [pol] // Simplify;`

It began to work faster.

Comment: And did it work?

Comment: It began to work faster.

Comment: But, with a high order $n = 24...38$, the calculation time takes about 5 - 10 minutes. Is it also not related to FindFit?

Comment: Yes, `FindFit` is still a bit slow.

Comment: Can I play with the method settings? AccuracyGoal, PrecisionGoal certainly affect the calculation speed. I am new to the intricacies of this function, so I need expert help.

Comment: I noticed you're not using `n` when you set up your filter. Also I think you should have a look at `TransferFunctionPoles` and `TransferFunctionZeros`. e.g `TransferFunctionPoles[ButterworthFilterModel[{"Lowpass", n, 1}, s]]` - and it doesn't have any zeros, only poles.

Comment: These commands did not speed up the calculation significantly

Answer (score 2):

You can get the poles of the Butterworth filter with different lowpass filter cutoffs without `FindFit`. Let me know if this is helpful:

```
order = 24;
cutoff1 = 1.5;
cutoff2 = 2.4;
btf1 = ButterworthFilterModel[{"Lowpass", order, cutoff1}, s];
btf2 = ButterworthFilterModel[{"Lowpass", order, cutoff2}, s];
poles1 = Flatten@TransferFunctionPoles[btf1];
poles2 = Flatten@TransferFunctionPoles[btf2];
topoints[complexes_] := Through[{Re, Im}[#]] & /@ complexes;
Plot[{Abs[btf1[I f]], Abs[btf2[I f]]}, {f, 0, 4}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"f", "α"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"c=" <> ToString@cutoff1, "c=" <> ToString@cutoff2}]
Graphics[{
  Red,    Point[topoints[poles1]],
  Orange, Point[topoints[poles2]]
}, Axes -> True, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: This can be used to get the roots and use them as initial parameter values. So, the answer is useful, but it is better to pay attention to the reasons for a sharp drop in the speed of calculations when working with a large number of optimized parameters.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're actually doing to the roots, mathematically? I got the impression you wanted to study the change in the roots when you change the cutoff, which is what this shows - in which case `FindFit` is not needed as it's too costly.

Comment: Yes, I’ll try to clarify. You change the parameters of the already known Butterworth filter structure. And I need to evaluate the location of the roots on the complex plane, if I change its frequency response, for example, add a slope of -20 dB / dec to the cutoff frequency.

Comment: If something else needs to be clarified, then I will be happy to answer you.

Comment: Presumably that's this part of your code: `tf = btf[[1, 1, 1]]/btf[[2, 1, 1]]`. If you turn this back into a `TransferFunctionModel` you can use my approach above without needing to use `FindFit`. There is also `TransferFunctionTransform` if you want to tweak an existing `TransferFunctionModel` - and this is recommended vs. modifying the internals.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in some cases the `TransferFunctionTransform` transforms a linear transfer function into a non-linear one? I need to keep the linear structure of the transfer function. As for your approach, it is acceptable. Except in cases where only an experimental data set is known (amplitude versus frequency) and it is required to form the most suitable transfer function for it.